# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on MAC

Tags: mysql, macos

I have installed 8.0.18 MySQL Community Server - GPL.
1. When I tried "sudo mysql" in terminal it is giving the following error.
"ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

2. Need to connect from Workbench
3. The MySQL server is up and running.
4. Giving the following error when trying to connect from workbench

   - Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306:
     Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found
5. when i ran this command "mysql -u root -p" it is showing MySQL console. Still not able to connect from Workbench

Comment: Are you using the workbench version for 8.0.18? Where is caching_sha2_password.so in your install? Ensure the mysql configuration has plugin-dir set to the directory where the file is.

Comment: I am using workbench version 6.3.10 CE.
Initially, I installed 8.0.18, but it was showing not compatible with the OS which is High Sierra.

Comment: caching_sha2_password was added in [Workbench-8.0.11](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/workbench/en/news-8-0-11.html). Sorry I don't know how to resolve OSX incompatibility.